# How to duplicate an array of UIViewController's

Tags: swift

I have on array of UIViewController's which I want to duplicate it.

```
var data: Array<UIViewController> = []
```

And this is my code:

```
data = viewControllers.map{($0.copy() as! UIViewController)}
```

But this code throws exception and I can't really tell what the issue is.
Can anyone point what the problem could be ?

Comment: What exception it throws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIViewController` does not conform to `NSCopying` protocol, that means it couldn't be copied. You may try to use `NSKeyedArchiver \ NSKeyedUnarchiver` to archive a view controller to `NSData` object and then unarchive it back. But it won't create the exact copy, the properties like `view` or `childViewControllers` will be most likely lost.

Copying UI elements is actually a bad approach. The correct solution would be to instantiate the view controllers one more time and set up required properties manually.